# Jqgrid Maximum number of rows

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

In my `ASP.NET MVC3(Razor)` application am using `jqgrid` for displaying data. It contains  number of rows per page like

`rowList: [10, 20, 40, 80, 100],`

while changing number of rows its working fine in localhost. But while uploading to `IIS` and if we are selecting `100 records it wont change`. The previous records only there.
If there any maximum number of row strategy there to Jqgrid? if nay body knows please share

Comment: Can you sniff the request/response in the IIS case with Fiddler or Firebug? It would help to diagnose the problem.

Comment: All those are working properly. I got json also. but it does not binds in grid.

Comment: I need to see it to try to analyze your issue (because in general the functionality works - I have used it several times with no issue). So please add request after change to 100 and part of response (you can skip the actual data part, the technical fields in response are the one in interest).